# null value in cellformatting

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, cell-formatting

I have a datagrid called `dgMember_Grade` that takes its data from a stored procedure.

One of its columns represent a date called `vacationStart`.

I want to color the rows based on cell value, but it gives me an error on the `foreach` line:

> Cannot convert type 'char' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell'

I tried the code:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dgMember_Grade.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in Myrow.Cells[26].Value.ToString()) // error on foreach 
            {
                if (cell != null)
                {
                    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                    DateTime expiredate = DateTime.Parse(Myrow.Cells[26].Value.ToString());

                    if (expiredate < date) 
                    {
                        Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code you can use:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dgMember_Grade.Rows)
{
    var cellValue = Myrow.Cells[26].Value;
    if (cellValue == null || cellValue == DBNull.Value)
        continue;

    DateTime expiredate = Convert.ToDateTime(cellValue);
    if (expiredate < DateTime.Now)
    {
        Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- You don't need 2 loops, You can simply use a loop betwen `Rows` and apply what you need based on `Myrow.Cells[26].Value`
- You can use events like `CellFormatting` or `CellPainting` or `RowPrePaint` to apply formatting.

Comment: what if the column ( vacationStart ) in another datagrid called ( dgavacation ) ....?

Comment: Like `Myrow.Cells[26]` you can use column index, or `Myrow.Cells["columnName"]`

Comment: i can't use       `var cellValue = dgVacation.Cells["vacationStart"].Value;`

Comment: What's the problem? I have no idea about 26 but `Myrow.Cells[INDEX].Value` (put ndex of column instead of INDEX) will work and the value is of type of `object`

Comment: i'll try to be more clear ... i want to colored the datagrid `dgMember_Grade` based on cell value ( a date ) in another datagrid called `dgavacation`

Comment: Not more difficult, `var otherCellValue = Myrow.Cells[INDEXofOTHER].Value;` then `var otherDate= Convert.ToDateTime(otherCellValue );`

Comment: i didn't mean that
i mean that i have two datagridview ... i want to colored the row in first one called `dgMember_Grade` based on cell value ( a date ) in the second called `dgavacation` ...

Comment: ِ@a.fathy dear a.fathi, the logic is the same, the only difference is reading a value from a row of another grid for example `dgavacation.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value` returns value of first column of first row of dgavacation, you can change it based on your requirement, but if you thinkk it is different and you need more help, feel free to ask a new question and let me know if you asked a new question :)

Comment: thanks  Reza Aghaei

the new question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146271/change-row-color-in-datagridview-based-on-values-of-a-cells-in-another-datagridv

Answer (score 1):

If you already know an index of the cell.
May be you are trying to do this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dgMember_Grade.Rows)
{
    if (Myrow.Cells[26].Value == null) {
        continue;
    }

    DateTime expiredate = DateTime.Parse(Myrow.Cells[26].Value.ToString());
    if (expiredate < DateTime.Now) 
    {
        Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```