# Change Row Color in Datagridview based on values of a cells in another Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell-formatting

I'm using c# winform sql server

In my database I try to manage the employee vacations in my small company so I was created two tables

first table called `tblMember`

`idMember` (PK, int, not null)

`memberName` (varchar(50), null)

that table related in one to many relationship to

second table called `tblVacations`

`idVacation` (PK, int, not null)

`vacationStart` (date, null)

`vacationEnd` (date, null)

`idMember_L`(FK, int, null)

then I created a form with two datagridview the first called `dg_member` populate its data (names from tblMember) throw a stored procedure

the second datagridview `dgVacation` populate the related data

now I want to colored with red the name in `dg_member` who absent today ( today is fall between `vacationStart` and `vacationEnd` ) and if the member is coming today ( today equal `vacationEnd` ) the name turn to green

i tried the code :

```
private void dgMember_Grade_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dgMember_Grade.Rows)
            {
                var cvStart = dgVacation.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value;
                var cvEnd = dgVacation.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value;

                if (cvStart == null || cvStart == DBNull.Value)
                    continue;

                DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(cvStart);
                DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(cvEnd);

                if (startDate < DateTime.Now && endDate > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else if (endDate == DateTime.Now)
                {
                    Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
```

but it gives me an error

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

[image: what i want]

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tmw Date  = DATEADD(day, 1,getdate())
select


m.MemberName
, case when t.idMember_L is null then 'False' else 'True' end as OnHoliday
, case when (select count (tm.idMember_L) from tblVacations tm where
    m.idMember = tm.idMember_L and
     t.vacationStart <= @tmw and t.vacationEnd >= @tmw ) > 0
     then 'False' else 'True' end as OnHolidayTomorrow
 from tblMember m
     left outer join tblVacations t
     on m.idMember = t.idMember_L and
     t.vacationStart <= getdate() and t.vacationEnd >= getdate()
```